Problem understanding docker build logs and caching
I have the following docker file:
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 as build

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY ./tools/ ./tools/
COPY ./pom.xml .
COPY ./ci_settings.xml .
COPY ./qa/ ./qa

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn clean package -s ./ci_settings.xml -DskipTests

FROM eclipse-temurin:21 as runtime

ARG JAVA_MEM_OPTS="-Xmx11g"
ENV JAVA_MEM_OPTS=${JAVA_MEM_OPTS}

when this is build in a gitlab runner i get:
> #0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
> #1 [qanswer-java internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
> #1 transferring dockerfile:
> #1 transferring dockerfile: 701B 0.0s done
> #1 DONE 0.5s
> #2 [qanswer-java internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:21
> #2 DONE 1.0s
> #3 [qanswer-java internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17
> #3 DONE 1.5s
> #4 [qanswer-java internal] load .dockerignore
> #4 transferring context:
> #4 transferring context: 69B done
> #4 DONE 0.4s
> #5 [qanswer-java build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b
> #5 DONE 0.0s
> #6 [qanswer-java runtime 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:21@sha256:b5fc642f67dbbd1c4ce811388801cb8480aaca8aa9e56fd6dcda362cfea113f1
> #6 DONE 0.0s
> #7 [qanswer-java internal] load build context
> #7 transferring context: 85.48MB 2.0s done
> #7 DONE 2.5s
> #5 [qanswer-java build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b
> #5 resolve docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b
> 0.1s done

The thing that is problematic is that he starts redownloading the base image. It first says:
#5 [qanswer-java build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b
#5 DONE 0.0s

so it seams cached, and actually it should be and then
#5 [qanswer-java build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b
#5 resolve docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b 0.1s done
#5 sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b 549B / 549B done
#5 sha256:62e6a9e10fb57f3019adeea481339c999930e7363f2468d1f51a7c0be4bca26d 1.79kB / 1.79kB done
#5 sha256:db741528e48aea788f63f806230fd5b3f0edcd0508dedd00357f069bc0c37ea0 7.27kB / 7.27kB done

he is redownloading it again. As a consequence also all the dependencies are redownloaded again. Also the numbering in the logs is confusing to me. Why does he start with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and then he restarts at 5? Is this normal?
Any clue?
Thank you
D063520
